# Input dialogue in a for loop is not working?

Tags: java, swing

I'm very new to Java and am trying to make a basic GUI for a compound interest calculator. I set strings to receive user input, and it works for the first two doubles, but when I want the String to take input for the length of the for loop, I get an error. Is what I'm trying to do not possible?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String p = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter initial investment: ");
        String r = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter interest rate (as a decimal): ");
        String y = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter time period (in years): ");

        double num1 = Integer.parseInt(p);
        double num2 = Integer.parseInt(r);
        double num3 = Integer.parseInt(y);
        double amount;

        for(double year = 1; year <= y; year++){
            amount = num1 * Math.pow(1 + num2, year);
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The answer is: " + amount, "the title", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Is your program getting compiled because you are comparing double and String `year <= y`.

Comment: Your program will not compile only.

Comment: And hint: years are typically **whole** numbers; so you *never* use floating point numbers to represent them. Meaning: your default for numbers should be int or long; you really only use floating point numbers for well ... floating point numbers. Not for years, days or months. And: **super bad** naming. num1 ... num3 says nothing. Just use investment, interestRate and periodInYears instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the double but the String.

Do that :

```
    for(double year = 1; year <= num3 ; year++){
        amount = num1 * Math.pow(1 + num2, year);
    }
```

Besides amount have to be initialized before being used otherwise it doesn't compile.

So replace :

```
double amount;
```

by

```
double amount=0;
```

---

**EDIT to answer to the comments of the OP.**

If you want to provide a floating value for the year, you should round this value to the superior value before entering in the loop and use it in the exit condition of the loop.

```
 String y = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter time period (in years): ");
  ...
 double year = Double.parseDouble(y);
```

And before and in the loop you should :

```
    double iteration = Math.ceil(num3);
    for(double year = 1; year <= iteration; year++){
        amount = num1 * Math.pow(1 + num2, year);
    }
```

For example, if you enter `0.4` for the year input, you round to `1.0` and therefore you loop once.

Comment: I get the following error after inputting the 3rd number.Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ".04"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at Sample.main(Sample.java:13)

Comment: Because you user Integer.parseInt() method and you provide not a int value but a double value. I understood your need. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot.

Comment: You are welcome :) Nevertheless, something annoys me. `num3` is never used as a floating value in your code. If you provide a decimal part for you year, should not you consider the decimal part of  `num3` when you compute the amount ?

Answer (score 0):

with this it should work:

```
    String p = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter initial investment: ");
    String r = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter interest rate (as a decimal): ");
    String y = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter time period (in years): ");

    double num1 = Double.parseDouble(p);
    double num2 = Double.parseDouble(r);
    double num3 = Double.parseDouble(y);
    double amount = 0;

    for(double year = 1; year <= num3; year++){
        amount = num1 * Math.pow(1 + num2, year);
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The answer is: " + amount, "the title", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

do not use Integer.parseInt(), if you want a double. also you can't compare double/integer with strings in your for-loop

Comment: The fix would be to tell him to **not** make num1 ... to be doubles. It was a good idea to parse ints; but a **stupid** idea to push the values into doubles!

Comment: @GhostCat if you read what the input should be, int is **not** the right type for the variables. how do you want to process decimal numbers as integers?

Comment: We are both right. num1 and num2 should probably be doubles. But num3 represents **years**.

Comment: yet the possibility exists, that you only want a half year

Comment: @MrHuebl if it works as you want, feel free to upvote and accept the answer. this applies for every question you ask, if there is a correct answer, upvote and accept it